# Не работает анимация круга с помощью stroke-dashoffset?

Tags: html, svg, svg-animation

Почему не работает анимация маски с помощью stroke-dashoffset?

```html
<svg id='h' version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id='mask'>
<circle r="30" cx="50" cy="50" stroke='black' fill="black" stroke-width='50' stroke-dashoffset='20 20'>
<animate
attributeName='stroke-dashoffset'
begin='h.click'
dur='10s'
repeatCount='indefinite'
values='50'
/>
</circle>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
</mask>
<circle r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

<rect width="100" height="100" fill='tomato' mask='url(#mask)' />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В svg, хорошо бы, всегда добавлять `viewBox`, если не укажите `width` и `height`, то изображение займёт весь экран браузера.  Если нужна адаптивность, указывайте ширину и высоту в относительных единицах.

```
<svg id='h' version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  width="35vw" height="35vh" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
```

Для анимации рисования бордюра окружности с помощью `stroke-dashoffset` необходимо знать  полную длину окружности.

При радиусе `r="30"` она равна  `2 * 30 * 3.14 = 188.4`
Также необходимо указать `stroke-dasharray ="188.4"` равное `stroke-dashoffset`

Ниже анимация вашего примера без маски, чтобы лучше понять принцип.
`stroke-dashoffset` изменяется от максимума (188.4) до нуля, обеспечивая тем самым рисование бордюра от нуля до полного круга.

*Анимация после клика*

```html
<svg id='h' version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35vw" height="35vh" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
<circle id="crc1" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" stroke='black' fill="none" stroke-width='40' stroke-dasharray="188.4" stroke-dashoffset='188.4'>
  <animate
attributeName='stroke-dashoffset'
begin='h.click'
dur='5s'
repeatCount='indefinite'
values='188.4;0'
/> 
</circle>
```

Теперь добавляем маску с анимацией окружности из вашего примера

```
<mask id='mask'>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
<circle r="30" cx="50" cy="50" stroke='black' fill="black"
```

Окраска элемента маски в чёрный цвет заставляет её вырезать отверстие

*Смотрите комментарии в коде для облегчения понимания основных моментов*

```html
<svg id='h' version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25vw" height="25vh" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<mask id='mask'>
<!-- Заполнение в маске цветом (зелёным) это цвет между черным и белым, делает изображение полупрозрачным -->
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />

<!-- Заполнение чёрным цветом вырезает отверстие -->
<circle id="crc1" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" stroke='black' fill="black" stroke-width='40' stroke-dasharray="188.4" stroke-dashoffset='188.4'>
  <animate
attributeName='stroke-dashoffset'
begin='h.click'
dur='5s'
repeatCount='indefinite'
values='188.4;0'
/> 
</circle>
</mask>
 <circle r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />  

  <!-- Маска вырезает из прямоугольника широкую строку --> 
  <!-- pointer-events="none" для того, чтобы клик проходил сквозь прямоугольник -->
  <!-- до circle с id="crc1" для запуска анимации маски -->
 <rect width="100" height="100" fill='tomato' mask='url(#mask)' pointer-events="none" />  
</svg>
```

Comment: _`width="35vw" height="35vh"`_ 1. Css для этого есть. 2. Это вообще валидно? 3. Размеры вообще указывать не надо, только viewBox.

Comment: @Qwertiy это валидно, также как и width="35%" в шапке svg/ А в CSS можно указать в случае, если svg  обернут в div  и указать ширину родительского контейнера

Comment: @Qwertiy скажите пожалуйста Вы тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161341/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-javascript-%d0%ba-2020-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83 можете чем-нибудь дополнить ?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT откуда взялось число 2 тут 2 * 30 * 3.14 = 188.4 ?

Comment: @Leks Формула длины окружности http://900igr.net/up/datas/240704/007.jpg